# Should we keep or delete or keep this answer?

Tags: discussion

While reviewing, I came across [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/96939/23379) as a late answer. Even if the question does not answer the OP's question directly, it provides some clear and detailed insight on the question on hand.

If we delete this one, (which IMO is the applicable option to this scenario, since this is more of an explanation, rather than an answer), OP may not get the benefit of having this insight.

Answerer cannot add these details in the comments as well.

What would be the best response to this type of situation?

Comment: I don't think every answer needs to be handed to the OP on a silver platter.  This looks fine to me.